# Splitting an array into two arrays of random lengths

Tags: matlab

I am trying to split an array of unknown length in Matlab into two arrays of random lengths. I think I was able to do it but it is a little clunky. I also would like to be able to save all of the possible combinations afterwards (a matrix for subarray 1 and a matrix for subarray 2), but I am having trouble doing this because it cant be saved in a matrix because they all have different lengths. Should I use cells instead?

Here is my code for splitting the arrays

```
Array = [1 2 4 5 6 2 3]
x = randi(length(Array))
newArray1 = Array(1:x)
newArray2 = Array(x+1:end)
```

Would like to run the above code a few times and save each combination of array1 and array 2 in its own matrix or cell like below

```
all_of_Array1  = [all_ofArray1:newArray1]
all_of_Array2  = [all_ofArray2:newArray2]
```

Thanks!

Comment: With `x = randi(length(Array));` it's possible that `newArray2` is empty. Use `x = randi(length(Array)-1);` if you don't want that

Comment: @LuisMendo but you also dont want `x` to be `1` for the same reason right? So shouldn't it be `x = randi(length(Array)-2)+1`?

Comment: @Dan No, because `randi` starts at 1, not at 0. `newArray1 = Array(1:x)` with `x` equal to `1` is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want a loop?

```
%//Pre-allocation
n = 10;
newArray1{n} = [];
newArray2{n} = [];

for k = 1:n
    %//Generate Array here if it changes at each iteration
    Array = [1 2 4 5 6 2 3]
    x = randi(length(Array)-1);
    newArray1{k} = Array(1:x)
    newArray2{k} = Array(x+1:end)
    %//Or replace the 2 lines above with newArray{k,1}=... and newArray{k,2}=...
end
```